# Meaning of $||\nabla_x u||$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, partial-derivative

[Here](http://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/heitzinger/node99.html) in the context of boundary value problems and the level set method for optimization the following notation

$$||\nabla_x u||$$

is presented as part of a PDE

$$F(t,x)||\nabla_x u||=1$$

Having weak background in differential calculus, what does

$$||\nabla_x u||$$

mean?

---

What I understand is that $u$ is some function, $\nabla_x$ is partial derivative with respect to $x$ and $||\cdot||$ is (some) norm. What I'm unsure about is what $\nabla_xu$ produces (I think it either produces a constant in the case of $ax$, a function of $t$ in the case of $a+t$, function of $t$ and a constant in the case of $ax+t$ or some other function of $t$, $x$ and constant) and what does $||\cdot||$ then do to it and what kind of norm is it.

Comment: Take a look at the "eikonal equation", e.g., in Arnol'd's "Lectures on Partial Differential Equations".  It is explained there very nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $I\subseteq \mathbb R$. Now if $u \colon \Omega \times I \to \mathbb R$ then $\nabla_x $ is given by:
\begin{align*}
 \nabla_x u(x,t) = \begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}(x,t)\\
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}(x,t)\\
 \vdots\\
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n}(x,t)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
And the norm is just as you suspected the eucledian norm $||x|| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$.

Hope this was what you had in mind.